# Scraping google with dorks in PHP

Tags: php, curl, scrape

I'm trying to scrape URLs from Google using a dork which is provided in the code.

Right now I'm using cURL, but it's saying 
"curl_init() is in undefined function"

So far I got:

```
 //This is the Pattern for URL finding
$pattern = "~^(http|ftp)(s)?\:\/\/((([a-z0-9]{1,25})(\.)?){2,7})($|/.*$)~i"; 
//Enter your dork here.
$dork = "inurl: login.php";
//Set the Useragent
$ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311";
//Initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=".$dork;
$timeout = 10;
curl_setopt($ch,CURL_OPT, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$ua);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);

$exec = curl_exec($ch);
$contents = curl_getinfo($ch);
//curl_close($ch);

//Set empty url array
$urls = array();
//Find urls on page you just grabbed ^
preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches);

//Assign the urls to the empty array urls
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match)
    {
        $urls[] = "{$match}";
    }

//Remove any duplicates in url array
$vurls = array_unique($urls);
//take out spaces
$urlStr = implode("", $urls);

//count number of unique urls
$count = count($vurls);

//Writing to text file
$fh = fopen('wp.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fh, $urlStr);
fclose($fh);

//Echoing # of urls found.
echo "Done. Found {$count} sites.\n";
```

I don't know what's wrong, and I'm trying to get it to scrape multiple pages as well.
But wondering on how I should tackle this.

if someone could point me in the right direction, it'd be very helpful, I don't need spoonfeeding.

Comment: `PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURL_OPT - assumed 'CURL_OPT' in /root/test.php on line 17

PHP Warning:  curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /root/test.php on line 17

PHP Warning:  preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /root/test.php on line 30

PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /root/test.php on line 33`

I've got the cURL working, I just need help with the code now.

Comment: I've never heard of CURL_OPT. did you mean CURLOPT_URL?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable **cURL** in PHP. To do this, you need to find this line in `php.ini` and uncomment it:

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

Make it this way:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [joomlashine.com](https://www.joomlashine.com/images/content/blog/website-development-tutorials/how-to-enable-curl-in-php/curl-enable-line.png))</sub>

---

In case you are using a **Windows 7** box...

1. Make sure that `php.ini` php engine uses is the one you think it is.
2. Make sure `extension_dir` in `php.ini` is correctly set to the ext folder.
3. Make sure `extension=php_curl.dll` in the `php.ini` is uncommented.
4. Make sure that there are two files in the `%windir%\system32` folder:

   ```
    libeay32.dll
    ssleay32.dll
   ```

If not, you need to copy these two files from the php folder

---

If you are on an **Ubuntu** box, you might need to install cURL this way:

```
apt-get install php5-curl
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

---

Then **restart the Apache server**. Use this code to check if cURL function has loaded.

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: I've done everything you provided and it's still not working, do the files have to be copied to System32 or just moved?

Comment: @JamalDante Should be copied. What server are you using? XAMPP, WAMP, or just Apache + PHP + MySQL?

Comment: I'm using WAMP Server, I think I'm just going to move it to my server and run testing in there.

Just a question though, does the code look right?

Comment: Oh WAMP Server, then it is awesome. What you need to do is, click on the little W icon on the taskbar, navigate to PHP » PHP Extensions » Check on `php_curl`.

Comment: Did you restart the Apache Server, make it this way: Click on W, click on Restart all services.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason why PHP wouldn't know of the function `curl_init` is if it wasn't configured with cURL support (https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php).

You can check the output of `phpinfo()` to confirm this.

Comment: Alright, I've got the cURL working on my linux VPS.

I'm getting a few errors from my code though:

PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURL_OPT - assumed 'CURL_OPT' in /root/test.php on line 17

PHP Warning:  curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /root/test.php on line 17

PHP Warning:  preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /root/test.php on line 30

PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /root/test.php on line 33